# PHP LDAP ldap_mod_replace

Tags: php, ldap

I am Trying to Create an Interface to Change Passwort of a LDAP User direct on the site for Users that arent used to LDAP. I am using ldap_mod_replace. for Changing it i need an Array $userdata. Now i want to set the Passwort from a Textfield.

How and what else do i need to create the array

This is the code from my save function.

```
function save($ds, $dn) {
echo "0";

 $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
 $repeatNewPasword = $_POST['repeatNewPasword'];
 echo "1, $repeatNewPasword, $newPassword";
 //newPassword $userdata
 //......
 echo "2";
 if ($repeatNewPasword == $newPassword) {
  echo "3";
    ldap_mod_replace ($ds, $dn, $userdata);

    echo "Erfolgreich, $ds, $dn, $userdata";
 }
else {
 echo "Passwords are different";
}
}
```

im not used to LDAP and dont know the function ldap_mod_replace at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the attribute-field the password is stored in. If the password-attribute is "password" you'll want to use this:

$userdata = ['password' => ];

Normally the value to the key is a numeric array but as it's a password it only contains one value and not multiple ones. Therefore you can also add the value directly.

Don't forget to hash the password according to the password policy used by the LDAP-Server. You might want to use the CLI-tool "ldappasswd" to properly hash the password. And you will need to bind to the LDAP-server either as the user you are changing the password for or as a user with administrative rights as the passeord-attribute normaly isn't readable and therefore not writable for others.